# Apache 2.4.10 VirtualHost index page not shown

Tags: firefox, virtualhost, apache2.4

To see my description of my problem directly, see the **Problem** part.

**Context:**

Running XUbuntu 14.10 and Apache 2.4.10.

I'm quite new to Apache so I'm trying to setup simple VH...with some success but I still have an issue. I read the docs and can't find what's wrong with my config. 
I would like to configure two virtual hosts : *myname.com* and *penguin.com*.

**Configuration**

Here is a short description (not exhaustive) of my current configuration.

*/etc/apache2/apache2.conf*

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options +Indexes 
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/html/flashlight/>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/>
        AuthName "Mon domaine"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.passwd
        Options +Indexes 
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myname.conf*

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    ServerName myname.com
    ServerAlias www.myname.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myname

    <Directory /var/www/html/myname>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/penguin.conf*

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.3:80>
    ServerName penguin.com
    ServerAlias www.penguin.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/penguin

    <Directory /var/www/html/penguin>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Both virtual hosts were enabled as described in the Apache docs using `a2ensite`. Apache was restarted with `/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful`. In `/var/www/html/penguin` and `/var/www/html/myname` I created simple `index.html` files to check if I'm on a virtual host or not.

Finally, I changed `/etc/hosts` to contain:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.2       myname.com
127.0.0.3       penguin.com
```

To check the configuration, I run `apachectl -S` and can see :

```
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.3:80           penguin.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/penguin.conf:1)
127.0.0.2:80           myname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myname.conf:1)
*:80                   www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
```

**Problem**

Now that I have two Virtual hosts configured, I try to access them.
When I try to access `penguin.com` in my broswer (Firefox), I see the `/var/www/html/index.html`  instead of `/var/www/html/penguin/index.html`. I have to explicitely write `penguin.com/index.html` to see the correct index page.

But when I access `myname.com`, the right index is served !?

Moreover, when I access those sites with Chrome, this problem doesn't occur and I see the right index page directly.

Is there a problem with my Apache config ? Or Do you think it's related to Firefox only (maybe it doesn't read `/etc/hosts` correctly) ?

**EDIT**

Just forgot to mention that when I access page via IP (127.0.0.2/3) I have the same issue in Firefox (only 127.0.0.2 works).

With `wget`, I get the files as expected. So I guess it may be related to browsers and not Apache config.

**EDIT2**

To "solve" the problem I replaced the loopback addresses in /etc/hosts with my local ip address. In addition I replaced the VirtualHost declaration by `<VirtualHost *:80>` in both files. Works fine now !

I still wonder why the Firefox couldn't get the right index when given the full loopback ip address though.

Sorry for the long post !

Thank you

Comment: you can try using http://172.0.0.3 in firefox if that working. Also look into apache access log and error log for hints.

Comment: I edited my post, but the behaviour is really weird in both cases.

Comment: i have posted an answer,  try and mark as answer if that resolved your problem.

Comment: I modified my /etc/hosts and replaced the loopback addresses with my local ip address and modified the VH declaration to <VirtualHost *:80>.

Works fine with both browsers !

Comment: can you cut the `EDIT2` into an answer and accept that ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case firefox will check your /etc/hosts as last option for name resolution.

You can try this workaround.

1. Open firefox and enter `about:config` in the URL.
2. Search `keyword.enabled` and set it to False.
3. Make sure in /etc/nsswitch.conf, `hosts` entry having `files` as first option.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your answer.  It doesn't seem solve the issue though.  I tried with wget and it seems to work fine. Do you think it's related to browsers interaction with /etc/hosts and not the apache config ?

Comment: Yes this has to be the browser issue. If this is an httpd issue, it wont be isolated to only Firefox. Can you provide /etc/hosts entry here?